# Discord.JS Won't Recognize the first option in a Poll

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've had this problem for quite some time now. I've tried to resolve it, and I can't understand why it's not working. I've used code that has worked before and still continues to work to this day. The main problem is that they are only counting the number of downvotes (represented by the thumbs down unicode) and not the upvotes (represented by the thumbs up unicode). How can I fix this? Thanks.

```js
(async () => {
 if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You need to specify a person!'); //If the statement is missing the second word, which in this case would be the person, it will notify you.
 const mappo = ['', ''];
 message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));
 let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(' '); //If the statement is missing the second word, which in this case would be the person, it will notify you.

 const embad = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('SimPoll')
  .addField('Topic:', `${msgArgs}`)
  .addField('Rules:', 'Vote for your side.');
 message.channel.send(embad);
 setTimeout(function() {
  const filter = (reaction) => mappo.includes(reaction.emoji.name);
  message
   .awaitReactions(filter, { time: 6000 })
   .then((collection) => {
    //not the most optimal way to do it
    const upvotes = message.reactions.cache.map(
     (r) => `${''} ${r.users.cache.size}`
    )[0]; //This can count the number of reactions. It's quite difficult to make.
    const downvotes = message.reactions.cache.map(
     (r) => `${''} ${r.users.cache.size}`
    )[1];

    if (upvotes < downvotes) {
     message.channel.send('Majority has ruled in the favor of No.');
    } else if (upvotes == downvotes) {
     message.channel.send('The scales are balanced.');
    } else {
     message.channel.send('Majority has ruled in the favor of Yes.');
    }
   })
   .catch(console.error);
 }, 2000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing two strings against each other, not two numbers. I'm not really even sure what you're trying to do by mapping each reaction into a string displaying the emoji and then the user count.

Instead of mapping the collection into an array and then using `[0]` and `[1]` to get the first and second elements, you can just use [`Collection#first(2)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first%60). This will more efficiently get the first two elements which you can then assign to variables using array restructuring.

```js
const [upvoteReaction, downvoteReaction] = message.reactions.cache.first(2);
```

From there you can compare [`MessageReaction#users#cache#size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=cache)

```js
const upvotes = upvoteReaction.users.cache.size;
const downvotes = dovoteReaction.users.cache.size;

if (upvotes < downvotes) {
  // ...
} else if (upvotes === downvotes) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```